# Vim insert mode completion for sentences

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I would like to have insert mode completion for sentences rather than lines in vim.

`C-x C-l` completes lines, but cannot complete sentences that do not start with a new line.

For example:

```
I have a dog. My dog's name is Spot.
```

I want to be able to type:

```
My dog
```

then hit a key to complete the sentence.

What is the best way to do this? A [thread with the same title](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Insert-mode-completion-for-sentences-td1185117.html) did not have a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try C-x C-u.  You will need to define the completion as described in the complete-functions section of the vim help.  Type:

```
:help complete-functions
```

To see this section.  Similarly,

```
:help i_^X
```

(where ^X is the C-x character) will show you the section that describes this mode.  Keep in mind that sentences typically end with the pattern /.  /.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. This is currently a bit beyond my level of knowledge, but I'll post if I find a specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

I modified my thesaurus completer to do sentence completion.
Some enhancements would be 
Complete using PWD/*, Gutenberg/books/*, 
Better regex using context around cursor.

```
" What: Complete sentence
" Usage: :so % <CR> Get sentence[press C-x C-o]
" How:  Get sentence completions using perl from current  file

set completeopt+=menuone

set omnifunc=MoshCompleteSentence
function!    MoshCompleteSentence(findstart, base)
    " == First call: find-sentence-backwards, see :help omnifunc
    if a:findstart
        let s:line = getline('.')
        let s:wordStart = col('.') - 1
        " Check backward for a sentence_prefix
        while s:wordStart > 0 && s:line[s:wordStart - 1] =~ '[A-Za-z0-9 _,]'
            let s:wordStart -= 1
        endwhile
        return s:wordStart

    else
        " == Second call: grep for sentence_regex, output: list of sentences
        let a:sentence_regex = a:base
        " in regex trim spaces
        let a:sentence_regex = substitute( a:sentence_regex,'\v^\s*(.{-})\s*$','\1','')
        " in regex change punctuation as dot.
        let a:sentence_regex = substitute(a:sentence_regex,'\W','.','g')
        " grep using perl
        let s:cmd='perl -ne '' '
            \.'chomp;'
            \.'next if m/^[;#]/;'
            \.'if( /('.a:sentence_regex.'.{1,30})/io ){'
            \.'   print qq/$1;;/ '
            \.'}'
            \. ' '' '
            \.expand("%:p")
        " == To debug: redir echom to file
        " redir >> c:/tmp/vim.log
        echom s:cmd
        let   s:rawOutput = system(s:cmd)
        let   s:listing = split(s:rawOutput, ';;')
        " echom join(s:listing,',')
        " redir END
        return s:listing
    endif
endfunction
```